# Rails 5 Regular Tasks Without Cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cron

I'm new to Rails so I'm not sure if this is a stupid question but...

I have to run regular tasks to populate data to my Rails app. Today I use the whenever gem to create Cron entries to run these tasks on my system. I want to migrate my Rails app to Docker so that I can scale it more easily. I know that in Drupal(PHP) there is Poorman's Cron which uses requests to drive schedules.

**Is there a way to implement scheduling inside Rails without using Cron or a better way of managing regular tasks that works well with Rails?**

Comment: You could use sidekiq+sidetiq.

Comment: Sidetiq seems to be no longer maintained

Comment: ah yes. Well, nevermind then.

Comment: Sidekiq and Resque seems to be a good alternative on a cluster though it'll take some work to get up and running.

Comment: scratch that...looks like resque and resque-scheduler are were i need to be

Comment: `resque-scheduler` and most of these gems run cron under the hood.

Comment: rufus-scheduler says it uses threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to implement scheduling inside Rails without using Cron
>   or a better way of managing regular tasks that works well with Rails?

Cron is pretty much the go to tool for running scheduled activities on *nix system and most gems actually leverage cron under the hood, in fact avoiding cron is probably a lot more work unless you want to use a third party service.

One of the new features of Rails 5 is [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html):

> Active Job is a framework for declaring jobs and making them run on a
>   variety of queuing backends. These jobs can be everything from
>   regularly scheduled clean-ups, to billing charges, to mailings.
>   Anything that can be chopped up into small units of work and run in
>   parallel, really.

It can be used with several backends:

- [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job)
- [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/ActiveJob)
- [Sucker Punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch#active-job)
- [Queue Classic](https://github.com/QueueClassic/queue_classic#active-job)

Comment: I don't see any method of using ActiveJob to defer jobs to a specific day/time. Can you update your answer with references?

Comment: `GuestsCleanupJob.set(wait_until: Date.tomorrow.noon).perform_later(guest)` - read the guide  its very straight forward. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job

Comment: I just used orats to generate a complete Rails environment and added a job set to kick off at a time...and it worked! Awesome!

Comment: I ended up using sidekiq-cron for recurring tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I created https://github.com/Ebbe/arask to keep stuff simple.

No need to install anything (other than the gem) or setup anything outside of rails. No background process, except for the actual job.

Add `gem 'arask'` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install`, `rails generate arask:install` and `rails db:migrate`.

Now you can setup your tasks in the file config/initializers/arask.rb:

```
arask.create script: 'puts "IM ALIVE!"', interval: :daily
arask.create task: 'my:awesome_task', interval: :hourly
arask.create task: 'my:other_awesome_task', interval: 2.hours
```

The tasks will automatically run if the server is running.